Any notation for incomplete factorals?
A nephew who plays poker asked me how many combinations of five cards there are from one deck.  I came up with:
52! / (52 - 5)! / 5!
... which I believe is correct, however it occurred to me that it would be more elegant if one could simply restrict the expansion of the factoral to five iterations.  Making it up, something like:
(52->48)! / 5!
... any such thing?  CPU cycles are cheap these days, but still, the official equation basically does a whole lot of multiplications that then have to be divided out again, it seems inelegant.

Indeed the sited previous answer is exactly on point, thanks.

The word is "factorial" not "factoral"

Thanks.  Nut's I think I've had it wrong for a very long time, easy to overlook.

Ultimately, it seems you want to find a way to compactify expressions of the type
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
$$
since these are equal to
$$
\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1)}_{\text{$k$ factors appear}}
$$
A standard notation for these is simply $\,_nP_k$ (Wikipedia) or the use of the Pochammer symbol or falling factorial as $(n)_k$ or $n^{\underline k}$.
